# Pusher subscription fails silently

Tags: pusher

I am subscribing to a channel in Pusher on my local machine using the Javascript SDK, and I don't get any error.
However, when I publish an event to that channel it is not received by the subscriber.

I've looked at Pusher's debug console and saw that the message is indeed sent but the subscription never occurs, as the connection is somehow interrupted, apparently prior to the subscription request (i.e I get a disconnection message, as shown in the console screenshot below).

the code is pretty boilerplate:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('PUSHER_KEY');

channel = pusher.subscribe('game'  + game.gameId);

channel.bind('statusChange', function(game) {

      console.log("GOT PUSHER - STATUS " + game.status);

      $scope.game.status = game.status;

    });
```

Examining the `channel.subscribed` property shows that the subscription failed as it equals `false`. I am at the sandbox plan (max 20 connections) and am only using 2 connections. 
What can disrupt the connection?

The channel object:

[image]

Console screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's the issue exactly but enabling the logs on the client side might help your find it:

```
Pusher.log = function(message) {
  if (window.console && window.console.log) {
    window.console.log(message);
  }
};
```

There's some resources on the website to debug that kind of problem too: http://pusher.com/docs/debugging

Comment: You can also just set `Pusher.logToConsole = true`. (Note: that's the constructor, not the pusher client instance)